# Create particle system via Python API scripting

Tags: python, scripting, particles, properties

I am having trouble creating an emitter via python scripting (using `Blender 3.2.1`).

My problem is the following:
suppose I have a cylinder and a plane (which will play the emitter role).

I can create those by writing

```
import bpy

# create plane
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add()
emitter = bpy.context.object
emitter.name = "Emitter"

# Create cyclinder
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add()
my_cyl = bpy.context.object
my_cyl.name = "My_Cyl"
my_cyl.select_set(False)

# Select (only) the emitter
objectToSelect = bpy.data.objects[emitter.name].select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = objectToSelect
```

From there, if I use the graphical user interface (GUI), select the plane, go in "`Particle Properties`", and click on `Add Particle System Slot`, the `info` displays

```
bpy.context.space_data.context = "PARTICLES"
bpy.ops.object.particle_system_add()
```

If in my script I write those above lines, I get the error message

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\simple_tests.blend\script001.py", line 18, in <module>
AttributeError: 'SpaceTextEditor' object has no attribute 'context'
```

My question is:
how can I manage to write the script to make it such that the plane is the emitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import bpy

# create plane
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add()
emitter = bpy.context.object
emitter.name = "Emitter"


bpy.ops.object.particle_system_add()


# Create cyclinder
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add()
my_cyl = bpy.context.object
my_cyl.name = "My_Cyl"
my_cyl.select_set(False)
```

Why do you want to make it that complicated? If you create a new object, it is the current active object which the ops operators use. If you create your cylinder later, you don't have to select that manually.

Comment: Hi @Chris your answer did the trick, thank you very much. I was wondering how it could be done through a function, which would be easier than copy-pasting always the same code?

Comment: i understand that. Then you should phrase exactly that in your question - then my answer would be different ;) please just open a new post with your question -> you can open as many posts as you want.